# Create json hierarchy tree from two-column dataframe (Python3) for d3 collapsible tree visual

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, tree

I have a dataframe with two columns: Employee and Reports_to. Every employee reports to someone, all the way up to the CEO. I would like to convert this into a json file that can be consumed by a collapsible d3 tree (as per this great link: [d3 collapsible tree](https://kyhau.github.io/d3-collapsible-tree-demo/collapsible_tree.html)). Would make for a great org chart that can be kept up-to-date with little/no manual effort.

[image: Collapsible org chart]

I have been able to convert the df into the correct json format as shown in the simple example below. However, I did this very painfully in Excel and then copied and pasted the `.append` strings into Jupyter (!).  **Here is my question: Is there an elegant way of converting in Python3 the 2-column df into the required dict?**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

#_Lx refers to the level in the organisation, where Jackie_L1 is the CEO
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
['Jo_L3','Jane_L2'],
['Jon_L3','Jane_L2'],
['James_L3','Jerry_L2'],
['Joan_L3','Jerry_L2'],
['Jane_L2','Jackie_L1'],
['Jerry_L2','Jackie_L1'],
['Jill_L2','Jackie_L1']]))
df.columns = ['Employee','Reports_to']
df 

Employee    Reports_to
Jo_L3       Jane_L2
Jon_L3      Jane_L2
James_L3    Jerry_L2
Joan_L3     Jerry_L2
Jane_L2     Jackie_L1
Jerry_L2    Jackie_L1
Jill_L2     Jackie_L1

#start with the root node and work over to the right (down the organisation) to provide the required json:
tree = {'parent': 'null', 'name': 'Jackie_L1', 'edge_name': 'Jackie_L1', 'children': []}

tree['children'].append({'parent': 'Jackie_L1', 'name': 'Jane_L2', 'edge_name': 'Jane_L2', 'children': []})
tree['children'].append({'parent': 'Jackie_L1', 'name': 'Jerry_L2', 'edge_name': 'Jerry_L2', 'children': []})
tree['children'].append({'parent': 'Jackie_L1', 'name': 'Jill_L2', 'edge_name': 'Jill_L2', 'children': []})

tree['children'][0]['children'].append({'parent': 'Jane_L2', 'name': 'Jo_L3', 'edge_name': 'Jo_L3', 'children': []})
tree['children'][0]['children'].append({'parent': 'Jane_L2', 'name': 'Jon_L3', 'edge_name': 'Jon_L3', 'children': []})
tree['children'][1]['children'].append({'parent': 'Jerry_L2', 'name': 'James_L3', 'edge_name': 'James_L3', 'children': []})
tree['children'][1]['children'].append({'parent': 'Jerry_L2', 'name': 'Joan_L3', 'edge_name': 'Joan_L3', 'children': []})
```

Here is the resulting dict required by the d3 tree:

```
{'parent': 'null',
 'name': 'Jackie_L1',
 'edge_name': 'Jackie_L1',
 'children': [{'parent': 'Jackie_L1',
   'name': 'Jane_L2',
   'edge_name': 'Jane_L2',
   'children': [{'parent': 'Jane_L2',
     'name': 'Jo_L3',
     'edge_name': 'Jo_L3',
     'children': []},
    {'parent': 'Jane_L2',
     'name': 'Jon_L3',
     'edge_name': 'Jon_L3',
     'children': []}]},
  {'parent': 'Jackie_L1',
   'name': 'Jerry_L2',
   'edge_name': 'Jerry_L2',
   'children': [{'parent': 'Jerry_L2',
     'name': 'James_L3',
     'edge_name': 'James_L3',
     'children': []},
    {'parent': 'Jerry_L2',
     'name': 'Joan_L3',
     'edge_name': 'Joan_L3',
     'children': []}]},
  {'parent': 'Jackie_L1',
   'name': 'Jill_L2',
   'edge_name': 'Jill_L2',
   'children': []}]}
```

I convert `tree` to the json file like this:

```
with open('C:/Python37/input_graph_tree.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tree, outfile)
```

Instructions for getting the collapsible tree running on a desktop is in the link above although you need to use `python -m http.server 8080` to kick it into action, not `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, thanks to Jonathan Eunice from here [create tree](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261074/process-to-generate-hierarchical-structure-based-on-relational-data/261082#261082).

```
#using the df example above, add a row for the top person:
lastrow = len(df)
df.loc[lastrow] = np.nan
df.loc[lastrow, 'Employee'] = 'Jackie_L1'
df.loc[lastrow, 'Reports_to'] = '' #top person does not report to anyone

#create a new column called eid that is a copy of Employee (to make the 'buildtree' function below work):
df['eid'] = df['Employee']
df = df[['eid', 'Employee', 'Reports_to']] #get the order right

#then run this
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

def show_val(title, val):
    sep = '-' * len(title)
    print ("\n{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(sep, title, sep))
    pprint(val)

def buildtree(t=None, parent_eid=''):
    """
    Given a parents lookup structure, construct
    a data hierarchy.
    """
    parent = parents.get(parent_eid, None)
    if parent is None:
        return t
    for eid, name, mid in parent:
        if mid == '': report = {'parent': 'null', 'name': name, 'edge_name': name }
        else : report = {'parent': mid, 'name': name, 'edge_name': name }
        if t is None:
            t = report
        else:
            reports = t.setdefault('children', [])
            reports.append(report)
        buildtree(report, eid)
    return t

people = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))

parents = defaultdict(list)
for p in people:
    parents[p[2]].append(p)
tree = buildtree()
show_val("data", tree)

#which gives you:
----
data
----

{'children': [{'children': [{'edge_name': 'Jo_L3',
                             'name': 'Jo_L3',
                             'parent': 'Jane_L2'},
                            {'edge_name': 'Jon_L3',
                             'name': 'Jon_L3',
                             'parent': 'Jane_L2'}],
               'edge_name': 'Jane_L2',
               'name': 'Jane_L2',
               'parent': 'Jackie_L1'},
              {'children': [{'edge_name': 'James_L3',
                             'name': 'James_L3',
                             'parent': 'Jerry_L2'},
                            {'edge_name': 'Joan_L3',
                             'name': 'Joan_L3',
                             'parent': 'Jerry_L2'}],
               'edge_name': 'Jerry_L2',
               'name': 'Jerry_L2',
               'parent': 'Jackie_L1'},
              {'edge_name': 'Jill_L2',
               'name': 'Jill_L2',
               'parent': 'Jackie_L1'}],
 'edge_name': 'Jackie_L1',
 'name': 'Jackie_L1',
 'parent': 'null'}

#then write to json:
with open('C:/Python37/input_graph_tree.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tree, outfile)
```

...and follow the instructions to show the d3 tree in your browser as per the OP. This should give you the tree as shown in the OP. This falls over if the tree is too big, but you can create one main branch at a time and combine them into one tree at the end (not easy though).